# TFS WorkItem Validation error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, validation, tfs, tfs-workitem

So here's the case: I am trying to create a Task WorkItem. I have to get the data from a `dataGridView`, which I think I managed to. But the fun part comes when I try to save, or validate the WorkItem. No matter what value `State` has, the validator always comes with `InvalidListValue` on execution of `wiTask.Validate();`. I have tried even hard-coding the State's value, but nothing happens. There is one thing that bothers me a bit - in the Validation array the error comes within the `Status` property, where the actual control has only `State` available. Here are some code and a snippet of the error bit:

```
WorkItem wiTask = new WorkItem(workItemType)
{                                
  Title = form1.dg_taskView.Rows[rows].Cells["titleDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString() + " " + form1.tb_details.Text,
  Description = form1.dg_taskView.Rows[rows].Cells["descriptionDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString(),
  AreaId = int.Parse(form1.dg_taskView.Rows[rows].Cells["areaIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString()),
  AreaPath = form1.dg_taskView.Rows[rows].Cells["areaPathDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString(),
  IterationId = int.Parse(form1.dg_taskView.Rows[rows].Cells["iterationIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString()),
  IterationPath = form1.dg_taskView.Rows[rows].Cells["iterationPathDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString(),
  State = form1.dg_taskView.Rows[rows].Cells["stateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString()

};
ArrayList result = wiTask.Validate();                              
wiTask.Save();
var hierarchicalLink = _workItemStore.WorkItemLinkTypes["System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy"];
                            userStory.WorkItemLinks.Add(new WorkItemLink(hierarchicalLink.ForwardEnd, wiTask.Id));
                            userStory.Save();
```

[image]

Comment: By default, all Tasks will be created in a New state and you cannot specify anything else.  Leave it blank and TFS will take care of it, setting the state to New.  Have you changed the state flow of that Work Item definition?

Comment: I just commented out the `State` line - the result is the same. What do you mean by state flow ?

Comment: I meant the states and the state transitions of the Task item.  Default is nothing to "New" so can't begin in another state and then you can move to  "In Progress" etc.  Is "Status" a custom field you've added?  Does it pull values from a global list?

Comment: `Status ` is a default field, definitely not created by me(just ran a dict search in the whole project). Everything I am doing towards this WorkItem is the code above + typing in values into an editable `DataGrid` view.

Comment: What is in the "result" ArrayList after you call Validate?

Comment: One item - the work item I want to save.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85122/discussion-between-rerwinrr-and-phantomazi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns - the validation returns to the array the column that has issues. After further examination the issue is resolved by specifying to `Assigned to` name, which is part of the project contributors' list.